# How can I keep the information confidential?

Tags: c#, database, authentication

I want to write a C# application, which need to connect to database and get some information back. I was thinking if I just the connection string in my C# application directly, then the user may be very easy to get the connection string and login to my sql server directly, once that happened they can select all the information they want !
So is there any good solution for this ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had a similar requirement.  I addressed it by taking my connection string and encrypting it using the Rijndael encryption logic (check it out in System.Security.Cryptography).  It's very easy to use.  A friend of mine has been attempting to crack this for the past 19 months, using a series of Rainbow tables - yes, he has way too much time on his hands - and has told me that "our solar system will probably go dark before I can get in."  I laughed.  Way too much free time.

I simply took my connection string, which I do store in an XML file (so I can change it out if needed) and encrypted it.  My app, as part of its initialization process, reads in this value - decrypts it - then, connects and opens the database.

Something like "I am a piece of data that is to be encrypted"  .....  once encrypted ends up something like ..... "V27AsTNsJA+BEwoGR2PbiZum5puwiLbfMa41ens8r8sSiEnn6FiT+k8ImEft
Qba8ziCpie94s3bEwcPekqRfhO1Noc8lVeERyezmtqN9/0ZgmzJbNbl/3emTLLfb0Qpj" .... which obviously isn't going to be very useful to someone trying to break in.

It's worth pointing out that even with a lowly 128-bit encryption (this supports 256-bit also) remember that there are 2 raised to the power of 128 possible values, or 3.4 e+38.  Think what a huge number that is:

340,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

If you attempt to crack this, for example, at the rate of 1 trillion attempts per second (1,000,000,000,000 / second) it could potentially take you 3 million million million years to get it.  Of course, you might get it on the first guess .... probably not, though.

A 256-bit key is 1.15 e+77 and a 512-bit key is 1.34 e+154 possible values.

Comment: That's the way , i am also doing it.

Comment: During the initialization process, you say it decrypts the connection string.  Is this decryption key also stored in the app or is it typed in by you at runtime?

Comment: @jskaggz - I honestly can't imagine trying to type a key or IV ... you'd make allot of errors doing it (or at least I would). It's a part of the application itself, but it's obfuscated in case someone tries to reverse engineer the app to get it that way.  There's actually several ways of handling this issue - mine allows for me to remotely "push" new crypto to the app because the encryption is also used for communications too, and swapping out crypto makes it all but impossible for anyone to penetrate security.

Comment: I think I like the idea of being able to push new crypto in, that makes a lot of sense.  Typically when I've seen people encrypt the primary password in the connection string, there's inevitably another password that's used to decrypt the primary in the configuration file, which is rather like leaving the key under the doormat.

Comment: @jskaggz - depending on your needs you do not need to have a user-entered value to decrypt the connection string that's used by the DB.  As the DB uses the "plain text" value, and the users won't be able to determine that because it's encrypted, the only way for anything to "crack" the value is by slipping in code that intercepts the call to open a connection and reads the plain text value.  Depending on how your implementation works that does become a possiblity by someone who knows what they're doing (most don't, though).

Answer (score 6):

The only way around this is a three-tier architecture, where your client software does not directly connect to the database, but to an application server, which controls the database credentials and what SQL gets issued.

It may also be possible (unlikely) to restrict the permissions that the database user for the client software has to only be able to select the data that the client app really needs (and nothing else). With this approach you would be creating specific views and only granting select permissions on those. Stored procedures are another tool here. However, that likely cannot cover all cases, and is a bit dangerous in case you accidentally granted too much or a bug in the database allows privilege escalation.

But if security is a concern, I'd go three-tier.

Comment: Do you mean I have to write a data access layer and add access control on that layer ? then every time I need to select data, I first send my username and password, after authorized then I can get the data I have permission ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to encrypt connection string in web.config. Here goes it [Encrypt](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/how-to-encrypt-connection-string-in-webconfig/). Also on top of this, use windows authentication (trusted connection=true). This makes sure that even if the user has the credential's, he still  can't login without his ID being added to ActiveDirectory/Domain.